# making a theme illustration

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wish to make a poster with the following presentation using TikZ.

[image]

Comment: Just write several nodes in various colors and you might want to play with the opacity option

Comment: Yes I can do it now, following daleif suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

As @daleif suggested, it is a matter of nodes and positioning them the way you want via `yshift` and `xshift`. Below, I've done two nodes for you. You can complete the rest of them. For the color, see this [list](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    [%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        place/.style={rectangle}
    ]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     \node[place,text=Goldenrod,opacity=.5,font=\fontsize{50}{50}\selectfont]  (A)    
     {$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^{2}} = \sqrt{\pi}$};
     \node[place,text=BrickRed,opacity=.9,font=\fontsize{20}{10}\selectfont,yshift=20mm] (B) [below=of A]   
     {$ e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]